# Understanding the use of "this" in two different contexts

Tags: javascript

I don´t get why "this" in this case returns "NaN" :

```
function Counter() {
  this.num = 0;
  this.timer = setInterval(function add() {
    this.num++;
    console.log(this.num);
  }, 1000);
}
```

And in this one it refers to "this.value":

```
function foo() {
    this.value = 'Hello, world';

    this.bar = function() {
        alert(this.value);
    }
}

var inst = new foo();
inst.bar();
```

I get that in the first case "this" is pointing to the Window object, I just don´t get why that´s the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `setInterval` `this` will be completely new and it will have no idea about `Counter`. You can use `bind` to pass the context `this` to setInterval

```js
function Counter() {
  this.num = 0;
  this.timer = setInterval(function add() {
    this.num++;
    console.log(this.num);
  }.bind(this), 5000);
}

Counter()
```

Alternatively you can also use arrow function

```js
function Counter() {
  this.num = 0;
  this.timer = setInterval(() => {
    this.num++;
    console.log(this.num);
  }, 5000);
}

Counter()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` function barely looks like this:

```
 function setInterval(callback, time, ...args) {
   // native complicated code
   callback(...args);
 }
```

What matters here is the call (`callback(...)`), as JS determines the context by how you are calling the function. In your second example the context of `bar` is `inst` as you call it as `inst.bar()`, so you directly tell js what `this` is. If you call a function direclty, e.g.

```
 const bar = inst.bar; 
 bar(); // call without context
```

you don't specify a context, and therefore `this` defaults to `window`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But shouldn´t SetInterval´s context be Counter, since it´s been called inside of it?

Comment: @hernan nope, thats not how js works.